# Transition for Text on reset

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to find a solution for this one but I can't. There s something that I keep missing... not sure what.

I have a project that when I click a image, the image will get an translate and also a **text description**.
The **text description** has a **smooth transition** and it looks cool.

Well, the question is.. how to make the reset(click on body or another image) to have the **same transition** for that **text description**?

This is how it look right now: https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-5150d8ffbf.gif

```js
function resetEnlargeEntityImage() {
    if(enlargedEntity != null) {
        enlargedEntity.style.transform = null;
        enlargedEntity.style.transition = null;

        enlargedEntity.classList.add("planet-svg-hover");

        document.getElementById("planets-description-paragraph").innerHTML = null;
        document.getElementById("planets-description-paragraph").classList.add("entity-description-js");
        document.getElementById("planets-description-paragraph").classList.remove("entity-description-appear-js");
    }
}



function enlargeEntityImage(clickedImage, clickedImageId) {
    let mediaQuery =  window.matchMedia('(max-width: 375px)');
    if(mediaQuery.matches) {
        window.location.href = `./${planetsName[clickedImageId]}.html`;
    } else {
        resetEnlargeEntityImage();

        var xToMove = 260 - 130 * clickedImageId; //260

        clickedImage.style.transform = "translate(" + xToMove + "px, 320px) scale(4.0)";
        clickedImage.style.transition = "transform 1s ease-in-out";

        clickedImage.classList.remove("planet-svg-hover");

        document.getElementById("planets-description-paragraph").innerHTML = descriptionSpaceObjects[clickedImageId];
        document.getElementById("planets-description-paragraph").classList.remove("entity-description-js");
        document.getElementById("planets-description-paragraph").classList.add("entity-description-appear-js");

        enlargedEntity = clickedImage;
    }
}
```

```css
.planets-description {
    color: white;
    font-family: "Barlow";
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 700px;
}

.entity-description-js {
    position: absolute;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    width: 600px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.entity-description-appear-js {
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s;
    width: 600px;
    left: 100px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="planets-description">
        <p id="planets-description-paragraph" class="entity-description-js"></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code you provided isnt showing anything, but maybe you could try uesing the "transition" property in css.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).